# Twitter Bootstrap Table of Dropdowns

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Say you have a generic table as such:

```
<table>
     <tr>
         <td class="box">ABC</td>
         <td class="box">DEF</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td class="box">GHI</td>
         <td class="box">JKL</td>
     </tr>
</table>

<ul id="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible, using bootstrap, to open a dropdown menu above a .box when clicked. (I'm assuming the easiest would be to use the bootstrap [.dropdown()](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns) method.)

```
$('.box').click ->
    ... make dropdown appear over $(this)
```

Libraries currently being used:

- Bootstrap v2.1.1
- jQuery v1.8.3

Comment: Your question is too vague. Where do you want to put the dropdown exactly and what should it do?

Comment: I just want the #menu to appear over a .box when clicked. It doesn't have to do anything.

Comment: Your question has more to do with positioning, because the jQuery code will succesfully open the menu when clicking box, but you probably want the menu to open exactly over this box?

Comment: You edit more quickly than I can comment ;)

Comment: Yea, I think Bootstrap wants the <ul> menu to be side by side of the item being clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a sufficient jQuery plugin that will do exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/